# How to redirect both stdout and stderr to a file

Tags: bash, stdout, io-redirection, stderr

I am running a bash script that creates a log file for the execution of the command

I use the following

```
Command1 >> log_file
Command2 >> log_file
```

This only sends the standard output and not the standard error which appears on the terminal.

Answer (score 580, accepted):

If you want to log to the same file:

```
command1 >> log_file 2>&1
```

If you want different files:

```
command1 >> log_file 2>> err_file
```

Comment: And just to save someone else the frustration, note that the order is important: `2>&1` needs to occur after `>> log_file`.

Comment: Why `>>` and not `>` ?

Comment: `>>` appends to the file, `>` overwrites. Search for "shell redirection" for more details.

Comment: A variation that views rather than saves log_file, e.g. when `make` vomits ten thousand errors that scroll off the screen: `vi <(make 2>&1)`.

Comment: and to see the output while it also gets saved to a file: `command 2>&1 | tee log_file`

Comment: What does '&' do in this context?

Comment: @xaxes: the `>&` is a single "token" here. See the "Duplicating File Descriptors" part of the bash man page (or the whole REDIRECTION section).

Comment: I have file1.txt and file2.txt in currect directory. When I run: 1. ls file{1..5}.txt 1>res.txt 2>&1: it gives correct output to res.txt But when I write 2. ls file{1..5}.txt 1>res.txt 2>res.txt: now it doesn't give correct output to res.txt, here in res.txt some output is omitted compare to what it should've been if we weren't redirect any stream. Why ?

Comment: This doesn't work for me. `time echo hi >> e.log 2>&1` the output of `time` to stderr ends up in the terminal and not the file.

Comment: http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/032 @falsePockets

Comment: @Rufflewind, thanks!  So why does the order matter?  Seems counter-intuitive to put the stderr redirection after the stdout redirection.

Comment: `2>&1` can be metaphorically understood as an assignment `stderr_handle = dup(stdout_handle);` in a C-like programming language.

Answer (score 282):

The simplest syntax to redirect both is:

```
command &> logfile
```

If you want to append to the file instead of overwrite:

```
command &>> logfile
```

Comment: Not sure when this operator was added but it may not be available in older versions of Bash. It does appear to be working on my machine which runs Gnu bash v3.2.48.

Comment: @CostiCiudatu the &>> operator does not seem to work in Mac OS X; safer to use Mat's solution imo.

Comment: @JamesFennell You're right, I wasn't aware of that. I upvoted the accepted answer :)

Comment: For Bash 4+, there is a version of this that will pipe to another command: `|&`.  See the comments on [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/a/16497456/1830736).

Comment: `&>` now works as expected on OS X 10.11.1 (seems to be bash 3.2), just for the record.

Comment: http://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/io-redirection.html mentions this syntax as being functional "as of Bash 4, final release".

Comment: I believe for appending  in any shell but Bash > v3.2 you need to use:

command >> logfile 2>&1

Comment: $(command 2>&1) works in bash 4.3.48(1) but $(command &>) does not.

Comment: I+1. Finally, `bash` matches the conciseness of the old `command >& logfile` in `tcsh`. It might almost be time for me to switch shells now!

Answer (score 50):

You can do it like that 2>&1:

```
 command > file 2>&1
```

Comment: +1, `2>&1` redirects file descriptor 2 (stderr) to file descriptor 1 (stdout)

Comment: Why do you need an ampersand here? i.e Why is it 2>&1 and not 2>1?

Comment: @btomtom5 `&` means file descriptor. How would write to a file named `1` otherwise?

Comment: @vstepaniuk I guess this depends on the context? Before ">" we don't need `&` to denote file descriptor because in this context only file descriptor is possible so `&` is implicit. After ">" the destination can be anything, so we have to use explicit `&` to specify that we are referring to a file descriptor rather than a file named "1"

Answer (score 10):

Use:

```
command >>log_file 2>>log_file
```

Answer (score 0):

Please use `command 2>file`
Here `2` stands for file descriptor of **stderr**. You can also use `1` instead of `2` so that **stdout** gets redirected to the 'file'