# How can I redirect stderr to a file?

Tags: bash, unix, find

What is the command required to redirect the standard error descriptor to a file called error.txt in unix?

I have this command so far:

```
find / -name "report*" ________ error.txt
```

Answer (score 10):

You can use the stderr handler `2` like this:

```
find / -name "report*" 2>error.txt
```

See an example:

```
$ ls a1 a2
ls: cannot access a2: No such file or directory  <--- this is stderr
a1                                               <--- this is stdout
$ ls a1 a2 2>error.txt
a1
$ cat error.txt 
ls: cannot access a2: No such file or directory  <--- just stderr was stored
```

As read in [BASH Shell: How To Redirect stderr To stdout ( redirect stderr to a File )](http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/redirecting-stderr-to-stdout/), these are the handlers:

| Handle | Name | Description |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | stdin | Standard input (stdin) |
| 1 | stdout | Standard output (stdout) |
| 2 | stderr | Standard error (stderr) |

---

Note the difference with `&>error.txt`, that redirects both stdout and stderr (see [Redirect stderr and stdout in a bash script](https://stackoverflow.com/q/637827/1983854) or [How to redirect both stdout and stderr to a file](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7526971/1983854)):

```
$ ls a1 a2 &>error.txt
$ cat error.txt 
ls: cannot access a2: No such file or directory  <--- stdout and stderr
a1                                               <--- were stored
```