# How to watch java error output by pages?

Tags: java, linux, terminal

I have a program which throws `StackOverflowException`. So the error output is very big and I can't read beginning of output from terminal. How can I watch all program output?

I know that there is something like pagination in terminal. I've googled about it and found advice to use `more` or `less` commands.

So I've tried...

`java Program | less`

But it doesn't work. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming you are using `bash4` you can use the `|&` to concat std error.

```
java Program |& less
```

Comment: Thanks! Your answer helps a lot :)

Comment: No problem! If this answers your question, up vote and mark correct :)

Comment: There is delay. I need to wait for few minutes before mark any answer.

Comment: FYI, this is probably the most portable solution if NOT using bash: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7526971/how-to-redirect-both-stdout-and-stderr-to-a-file

Answer (score 1):

You can redirect the output to a file

```
java myProgram &>file.log
```

Then you can tail , head or grep that file.

Comment: I've tried this, but there is nothing in created file. It is empty. And I don't know why.

Comment: I updated it adding the redirect of stderr to stdout

Comment: Now it works, thanks! But it is easier to use `&|` in such cases.

Answer (score 0):

Use a good IDE (Integrated Development Environment) such as Eclipse. Any decent IDE will have a debugger mode.

Java is a both compiled and interpreted language, which gives it speed and is also easy to debug.

IDE debuggers will walk you through the program execution step by step, which can help you to find errors in your program that you might not otherwise see.

Comment: Yeah, I know it. But sometimes it is faster to write small program in vim and then run it in terminal.