# Crontab visible in logs but still doesn't seem to run?

Tags: amazon-web-services, cron, root, aws-cli

I'm on an AWS server.  I wrote a crontab and placed it on the server under `/etc/cron.d`.  The contents of the crontab are the following:

```
SHELL=/bin/bash
PATH=/sbin:/bin:usr/sbin:/usr/bin
MAILTO=root
HOME=/

*/5 * * * * root <full-path-to-write-command> >> <full-path-to-txt-output-file>
```

After running `sudo service crond restart`, I check the logs by doing `sudo tail -f /var/log/cron`.

I can observe the cronjob in the logs:

```
<date-time-stamp> ip-<ip-address> CROND[12930]: (root) CMD (<full-path-to-write-command> >> <full-path-to-txt-output-file>)
```

However, when I check the `<full-path-to-txt-output-file>`, I don't see file being written to.

What could be the problem, if I see that the cronjob is executing?   Thanks

Comment: Perhaps there is an error occurring. You aren't capturing STDERR in your log file, just STDOUT. You might try looking at this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7526971/how-to-redirect-both-stdout-and-stderr-to-a-file You might also try running `sudo <full-path-to-write-command>` to see what happens.

Comment: I ran the command alone, as you suggest - it works just fine.

Comment: You might also look at this: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/49077/why-does-cron-silently-fail-to-run-sudo-stuff-in-my-script

Comment: `/path/to/command >> /path/to/file 2>&1` otherwise you are discarding the error stream.

Comment: There is no error when I run the command, though.

Comment: Actually, this is a different issue entirely.   Please see my new question:  http://serverfault.com/questions/721042/empty-events-for-aws-vpc-logs