# C stderr to a file

Tags: c, stdout, stderr

Hello I am writing a program in C. I start it like that after compilation.

```
/a.out <source.txt >output
```

I want all messages to be printed to the output.txt. However I would like to send errors to the console, not to the file. The problem is when i use this statement in my code:

```
freopen( "errors.txt", "w", stderr );
fprintf (stderr, "%s\n", s);
```

All Erros are also printed to the output.txt file not to errors.txt I would be grateful for any help.

Comment: How exactly did you invoke your executable with output redirection? Can you paste your command line?

Comment: Only way that this command is printed into output.txt is that you've redirected your stderr to some file.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [In C how do you redirect stdin/stdout/stderr to files when making an execvp() or similar call?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14543443/in-c-how-do-you-redirect-stdin-stdout-stderr-to-files-when-making-an-execvp-or)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to redirect both stdout and stderr to a file](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7526971/how-to-redirect-both-stdout-and-stderr-to-a-file)

Comment: Your question is contradictory: 1st you write " I would like to send errors to the _console_", and below you write that errors are also printed to output.txt and not to _errors.txt_. Please clarify. And also `/a.out <source.txt >output` wont write to `output.txt` but to `output`.

Comment: thank you for help. I just wanted to send my stdderr to different place than stdout. The answer below helped me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default the `stdout` and `stderr` are together routed to your console. However you can redirect the error stream to a file with the help of the following form of your command line: ./a.out  **2>logfile.log**. In that case the `stdout` will still come to the console, but `stderr` will go to the file.