# Gradle, how to print failed log to file

Tags: android, gradle

Command is gradlew assembleQW >a.txt.

When success, the log is all in a.txt.

But when failure, the reason for the failure is printed in the console.

[image]

[image]

Comment: try explaining the issue more in detail and what are you trying to say

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `>` only redirects `STDOUT` from the console to the file. If you want to also redirect `STDERR` you will need to use `2>`.

See [windows](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/110930/redirecting-error-messages-from-command-prompt-stderr-stdout) or [unix](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7526971/how-to-redirect-both-stdout-and-stderr-to-a-file)

eg:

```
gradlew assemble 1> a.txt 2>&1
```